# Track DDL and DML changes using flyway, Access FE and Postgresql BE

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, flyway

i am tracking DML changes in history table in postgresql using Access FE tracking system. 
Like in the link below but i am inputting data into postgresql BE:

[enter link description here](https://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut21.htm)

My boss wants to have possibility to give the version for certain state of database and revert it. And it means for DDL and DML changes.

For DDL changes i can use flyway - it is easy to use. 
But how to combine DML changes (inserting, deleting, updating data) from history log table in Postgresql with DDL changes (adding columns and tables) in flyway?

Please help Guys, 
I can not put DDL triggers in postgresql what i know.

Best,
Jacek

Comment: Why can't you have Flyway migration scripts with DML changes in them?

Comment: I think that i will change my concept. I will create event triggers ond DDL and triggers on DML and i will have all in one big history table. Because i do not want to use flyway :)

Comment: I'm not sure how that will help you revert changes as per your stated requirements. Flyway has both "up" migrations and "down" migrations (called undo scripts) which satisfy this very need.

Comment: hi @DavidAtkinson. thank you for your help and support.
I simply changed my whole idea. 
I will have one history table and i will create reverted SQL statements for each row. 

So you can rollback step by step , record by record.